# Reason for "referenced before assignment" warning for variables in trivial sequence of conditions

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings

Is there any good reason for the `Local variable 's' might be referenced before assignment` warning in this trivial piece of code:

```py
def nonsense():
    condition = True
    if condition:
        s = "I am set."

    if condition:
        print(s)
```

Screenshot from `PyCharm 2019.2.6`:

[image: warning example]

**Remarks:**

- I have experienced this issue in more complex (and useful) situations, but I want to point out that it even occurs in this trivial case of two identical conditions in a row.
- My naive assumption is that `condition` can not change between the two `if` statements under any circumstances. If this is true, I consider the warning a limitation of static code analysis.
- optional sub-question: What are your best practices for workarounds? Bloating the code by setting `s` in all cases, though not required?

Comment: You know that the condition can't change, but PyCharm can't figure that out.

Comment: Spyder3 doesnt through any flag at it, even if I insert 'del s' after s assignment

Comment: @pippo1980 Thanks for that insight! Though I am not sure whether I would prefer this behavior xD

Comment: Fyi: I just found that there is a Jetbrains issue addressing this PyCharm weakness: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-3344.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any good reason for the Local variable 's' might be referenced before assignment warning in this trivial piece of code:

Not really. It's just that the IDE thinks that since the assignment/initialisation `s='I am set'` takes place inside a condition `if condition:` (not caring what the condition is), it might be possible that the assignment did not take place. And thus the warning.

IDE's are not that intelligent after all!!